# Basic Standard Deviation Question - Curtain rails

Tags: standard-deviation, mean-square-error

Hopefully you guys can help me. I'm completely stumped by normal distribution and the like. No matter what I do, I can't get it right. Hopefully someone here can save me!

This is my question:

A curtain rail is manufactured to be approximately normally distributed with a mean $28$mm and a standard deviation of $2.7$mm. The Rails are required to be in lengths that range from $25.5$mm to $31$mm.

A) What proportion of curtain rails will be shorter than $27$mm?

B) What length is exceeded by $15\%$ of the rails?

C) What proportion of curtain rails will meet the specification?

D) What value of the standard deviation is required so that less than $8\%$ of the rods have a length smaller than $25.5$mm?

---

I have (possibly) figured out A.

So it would be that $P(Z<2.7) = 1-0.9965 = 0.0035$. So $0.35\%$ of rods will be the required length. Is that correct?

I can't even begin to figure out the others.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The question asked in A is what proportion of rails will be shorter than 27mm , not 2.7 mm., so the answer is actually 35.5%. Strictly speaking the question should should be "what is the probability that a rail will be shorter than 27 mm?". That this *will* be the actual proportion is a broad inference.

Question B likewise can be rephrased as the probability of a rail being in the 85th percentile or above and is the value of $x$ that satisfies the condition

$$
1-\int_{-\infty}^x p(\mu,\sigma,\xi)d\xi=1-D(\mu,\sigma,x)=0.15
$$

where $p()$ and $D()$ are the probability density and cumulative distribution functions. The answer is $x=$ 30.8 mm, using EXCEL's NORMINV function.

The answer to C is $D(\mu,\sigma,x_{max})-D(\mu,\sigma,x_{min})$ which you can calculate and figure out D on your own.

Comment: I'm sorry - You have completely confused me. I've managed to complete parts A and B now (thank you for the confidence check - I got almost the same answers). But you have just confused me with C and D. You've given me a formula I can't understand. What are the commas for? I'm not using excel, so they don't mean a great deal to me.